# Calling a stored procedure from another stored procedure does not produce results

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two stored procedures - `p1` and `p2`. `p1` change database and returns the data from the table `Table1` of a table type `table1_type` with some content, and `p2` simply returns what `p1` returned.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p1
  @Resp INT OUTPUT
AS 
/*Change database here*/
SET @Resp = 0;
SELECT * FROM Table1;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p2
  @Resp INT OUTPUT
AS 
DECLARE @tmp table1_type;
INSERT INTO @tmp EXEC dbo.p1 @Resp OUTPUT;
SELECT * FROM @tmp;
GO
```

If you make the next request

```
DECLARE @tmp dbo.table1_type;
DECLARE @Resp INT;
INSERT INTO @tmp EXEC dbo.p1 @Resp OUTPUT;
SELECT * FROM @tmp;
```

then the contents of the `Table1` table appear in the `@tmp` table and the `@Resp` variable becomes 0. But if you call the `dbo.p2` procedure, it will not return anything (`@tmp` will be empty) and the `@Resp` variable will will be empty too.

```
DECLARE @tmp dbo.table1_type;
DECLARE @Resp INT;
INSERT INTO @tmp EXEC dbo.p2 @Resp OUTPUT;
SELECT * FROM @tmp;
```

Why is this happening and how can you call a stored procedure that contains a call to another stored procedure so that what is expected is returned?

***This happens because you cannot use the `INSERT ... EXEC` construct inside a nested stored procedure.***

Comment: You can not create and store stored procedure output in a table. You can do it using function. You need to write insert into in the body of stored procedure.

Comment: Ok, @SurajKumar, would you answer me. If I need to use a function how can I get two values in a function - table (```@tmp```) and response status (```@Resp```)? In a stored procedure I can use ```OUTPUT``` parameter but not in a function

Comment: You can use table valued function.

Comment: I got it. But my stored procedures do some job (change database, not just return data like in my question). What can I do?

Comment: If I remove ```INSERT INTO @tmp ``` before ```EXEC``` my problem will be solved. But I need the ```@tmp``` to use it later

Comment: I'm sure this used to raise an error about not being allowed to nest `INSERT... EXEC` statements. You've not done something that'll hide an error from you have you?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, You are right, the error was, but it did not interfere with the execution of the code. Therefore, it was not immediately noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `OUTPUT` you can only get one single row.

You can use temp tables to share data between procedures. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_1 @par1 int,
                          @par2 bit,
                          ... AS
   ...
   INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE #mytemp
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_2 AS
   DECLARE ...
   CREATE TABLE #mytemp (col1 int     NOT NULL,
                         col2 char(5) NULL,
                        ...)
   ...
   EXEC sp_1 @par1, @par2 ...
   SELECT * FROM #mytemp
GO
```

In addition, you have many other options described in an [a great article written by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

**UPDATE - Safety:**

If temp table declared as #tempTable, then it is safe as those temp tables can only be accessed by the creating connection, and will be exist just only during of the execution  of the stored procedure. However, if you create a global temp table (with two signs ##tempTable), then those tables are not safe as they are exposed to all connections of the SQL instance.

**UPDATE - Availability:**

[As MSDN says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped
>   automatically when the stored procedure is finished. The table can be
>   referenced by any nested stored procedures executed by the stored
>   procedure that created the table. The table cannot be referenced by
>   the process that called the stored procedure that created the table.

So in our case, `sp_2` is a outer stored procedure and sp_1 is a nested stored procedure.

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to some problems, if more than one user is using these stored procedures?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just tried it on my local installation and it works.. Thanks.

Comment: @StepUp, I do not understand how ```#mytemp``` will be used in ```sp_1``` if it is declared in ```sp_2```, and is it not a global table?

Comment: @StepUp: I gave you my upvote, as I learned something :-) . I didn't acutally have the problem myself :-)

Comment: @DanStef it is nice that it was helpful:)

Comment: @Olejan I am glad that it helped to you:)